# How to check if my computer has a usb-c that can be used for display port

Tags: windows-10, usb, usb-c

So i have an old screen that i would like to connecto to my new Windows 10 computer.

This screen is ONLY VGA. So i want to buy a usb-c to VGA adapter. However ive read online that you have to have a Display port alternative usb-c port in your computer to support it.

My question is how do i check if my usb-c ports supports it?

Comment: Go to its website and check its specs.

Comment: Mine says it has: Thunderbolt 3 (USB Type-C) port. Will that be enough to buy for instance: https://www.av-cables.dk/usb-til-vga-converter/usb-c-3-1-til-vga-adapter-sort.html

Comment: Many graphics cards come with a dvi to vga adapter. So if your computer has a dvi port you could try that.

Comment: This is my computer: http://www.dell.com/support/manuals/dk/da/dkbsdt1/alienware-15-laptop/alienware-15-r3-setupandspecifications/back?guid=guid-64d4e0a8-3e3b-41ba-9943-ece5f354ac48&lang=en-us

Comment: FYI: USB-C's DisplayPort alternate mode and DisplayPort over Thunderbolt 3 (Type C connector) are actually different display signals. If you have a TB3 port go for a TB3->VGA adapter and you don't need to worry about support for DisplayPort alternate mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [your own link](https://www.av-cables.dk/usb-til-vga-converter/usb-c-3-1-til-vga-adapter-sort.html), the Type-C connector

> port Supports USB 3.1 Gen 2, **DisplayPort 1.2**, Thunderbolt 3 and also
>   enables you to connect to an external display using a display adapter.

However, the adapter of your selection doesn't need any Display Port, nor any Tunderbolt functionality -  it is a plain USB 3.0 to VGA converter. You don't need DP support to run your adapter and VGA monitor.

But I would strongly advise you to throw away your old VGA screen, and just buy a normal modern LED monitor 22" or 27". Some are under $100 these days. And you won't need any adapter for this. You will save money and waste less power. And preserve your vision.

Comment: You can still buy low-end LED monitors that are VGA only. It is an assumption that the OP's monitor *is* inefficient or bad for their eyes without seeing any model number. Also, it may be misleading to say "plain USB 3.0 to VGA converter". They're not video converters in the same sense as a Type-C to VGA dongle. Those USB-A "converters" are actually external USB GPUs with their own drivers and can vary in performance and capabilities by a lot.

Comment: not all USB-C 3.0 has DisplayPort support as I found out from my own experience:  https://superuser.com/questions/1614732/is-it-possible-to-upgrade-a-basic-usb-c-to-have-usb-c-alternate-mode