# Why do some docking stations have a double USB-C plug

Tags: usb-c, docking-station

The docking stations for both my Dell and my MacBook Pro have a double USB-C plugs to plug into the computer.  The plugs on the cable are perfectly spaced to match the spacing of the ports on the computer.

Many other docking stations only have one USB-C plug to the computer while apparently retaining all the same functionality (multiple monitors, ethernet, power pass through, USB A, etc).

What is the advantage of the double USB-C setup?  I presume higher bandwidth or power pass through but I haven't seen that.  How would the higher bandwidth be utilized if the docking stations with one plug already have multiple monitors and gigabit ethernet?

Comment: Can you show a picture of this port.

Answer (score 4):

If one of the USB C ports supports DP Alt Mode then connecting a monitor to the hub will effectively [disable some or all of the USB 3 Superspeed connection wires in favour of DisplayPort video](https://superuser.com/questions/1614732/is-it-possible-to-upgrade-a-basic-usb-c-to-have-usb-c-alternate-mode/1614767#1614767).

As a result a single USB C port hub may either have slower USB speeds, i.e. no 10gbps or even 5gbps, or fall back to USB2 speeds while a monitor is connected.

If you use 2 USB C ports then one port could be used for data while the other is used for DP Alt mode video.

Two ports would allow an effectively "full speed" USB 3 connection at the same time as a dedicated display from the GPU.