# Can I connect two monitors to my Asus VivoBook laptop? One via HDMI and one via USB C?

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, usb-c

I just bought an Asus Vivobook. The specs stated that it came with the following ports:

- 2 USB 2.0 A
- 1 USB 3.2 Gen 1 A
- 1 USB Gen 1 C
- 1 HDMI port

With this I assumed I'd be able to connect two monitors. The HDMI port works fine, however when I try to connect a monitor to the USB-C port (with a USB-C to HDMI converter), it does not work. The message I get is "Display Connection might be limited".

I was under the impression that USB-C supported display data, but apparently this requires some alt mode, which may or may not be available on my laptop (not sure how to find out). I am also not sure if the lack of this feature is what is causing my problem.

So my question is: Is there any way to connect two monitors (extended display, not duplicated) to my laptop, with the ports listed above?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

USB-C Supports display output as long as the motherboard is made to support having a display output on the USB C. Just because you have USB C does not mean you have [USB C Alternate Modes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB-C#Alternate_Mode_partner_specifications) which are required to allow DisplayPort or HDMI output.

> Alternate Modes are optional; Type-C features and devices are not required to support any specific Alternate Mode. The USB Implementers Forum is working with its Alternate Mode partners to make sure that ports are properly labelled with respective logos.

[Asus state that there should be an identifying mark](https://www.asus.com/support/FAQ/1042843/#) near the USB port showing what Alternate modes it supports, or your computer manual should indicate support. They also advise that the website page for your model should tell you what outputs are supported:

> **The product specifications of the computer are provided on the [ASUS Official Website](http://www.asus.com/). You can see the specifications of the interface in the interface area under the product specifications.**
>
> ①[Search] your computer name, click ②[Tech specs] , you can see the USB Type-C in the range of ③[Interfaces] Technical specifications of the interface.

Lacking any explicitly mentioned support for DisplayPort or HDMI over USB C you might be able to use a more conventional [USB DisplayLink adaptor](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Wavlink-Adapter-External-Supports-Resolution/dp/B076SX73LY) which is essentially a display card in the USB adaptor, but performance will not be great.

Comment: so how do I find out whether my motherboard supports it? If it does not support it, is there some other way to to connect a second monitor?

Comment: @WreckFish added more information. You might be able to use a more conventional [USB DisplayLink adaptor](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Wavlink-Adapter-External-Supports-Resolution/dp/B076SX73LY/ref=sr_1_3?keywords=external+graphics+card&qid=1640642893&sr=8-3) which is essentially a display card in the USB adaptor, but performance will not be great.

Comment: just checked the Asus website. it makes no explicit mention of display port of USB-C. Essentially, I'm stuck unless I want to return the product, it seems. This is extremely frustrating as I explicitly checked to see whether USB-C supports display data. Everyone gave a resounding yes. Here is one example from [Quora](https://www.quora.com/Can-I-connect-an-extenal-display-using-USB-C-not-thunderbolt-3). To rant a bit more, it would seem this is important info to include in the tech specs.  Anyway, one more shot in the dark: if I get a monitor with a USB-C port, would that work?

Comment: @OP - what about a docking station for the laptop?

Comment: @John already tried a docking station that hooks up to the USB-C... same issue. If you can think of a way around that, I'd be very grateful.

Comment: I looked on the ASUS Support Site and did not see anything definitive.

Comment: @John same. This is extremely frustrating. I specifically bought something that I thought would support two monitors. Every resource on the net says USB-C can support display and then I immediately find out it can't... Obviously nobody here's fault but... seriously folks?

Comment: @Mokubai how bad would the displaylink adapter be? I only use the machine for coding and chess. Would I notice lag?

Comment: @WreckFish for simple things I think that the displaylink will be fine, especially if you get one that actually states USB3. I mainly remember USB2 not really having enough bandwidth to be great, not seen USB3 ones. As an example of Asus showing display output I did find one of their laptops that does state display on the USB-C: https://www.asus.com/Laptops/For-Creators/ProArt-Studiobook/ProArt-Studiobook-Pro-16-W5600-AMD-Ryzen-5000-series/techspec/ `2x USB 3.2 Gen 2 Type-C support display / power delivery` That is a "pro" model while I don't see the "display" mentioned on other models.

Comment: Sadly this is one of those difficult to nail down things of USB C. It 100% *can* support display output but true support is determined by the motherboard manufacturer. It boils down to whether the manufacturer  spent an extra £5 on a chip capable of switching the USB to display lines, see my answer over here: https://superuser.com/questions/1614732/is-it-possible-to-upgrade-a-basic-usb-c-to-have-usb-c-alternate-mode

Comment: @Mokubai ok so I'm looking at display link adapters and people seem to have good experiences. I'm going to try it. The one I am looking at is [here](https://www.amazon.com/StarTech-com-HDMI-External-Video-Adapter/dp/B00O6G5ZGI/ref=sr_1_3?keywords=displaylink+adapter&qid=1640675746&sprefix=displaylink+a%2Caps%2C73&sr=8-3). It says it is for 1920x1200. My resolution is 1920x1080. I assume this will work but would like to make sure these things aren't super resolution specific, or anything.

Comment: @WreckFish  They shouldn't be super specific, they're just telling you the maximum it can do. Pretty much any resolution lower than stated should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently Asus Vivobook 15 only supports display through the HDMI port. So you can just have the laptop connected to one external monitor or you can purchase an HDMI to dual HDMI adaptor, although they seem so much more expensive than their USB-C counterparts.

Comment: I have Vivebook 15 Pro and it works with 2 external monitors (one ultra wide through HDMI and another full HD by USB-C).

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and have recently found a solution!

https://www.amazon.co.uk/StarTech-com-USB-Dual-HDMI-Adapter/dp/B0725K1MHH/ref=sr_1_3?crid=347PDV12MKPDF&keywords=star+tech+usb+3.0+dual+hdmi+adapter&qid=1664801777&qu=eyJxc2MiOiIwLjAwIiwicXNhIjoiMC4wMCIsInFzcCI6IjAuMDAifQ%3D%3D&sprefix=star+tech+usb+%2Caps%2C79&sr=8-3

This adapter EXTENDS the display and does not DUPLICATE IT.

I have been using it a litter over a week and it has worked perfectly so far. Hope this helps.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1149265)