# Do you need a special USB-C port to connect a display?

Tags: hdmi, displayport, usb-c

I've been getting more and more confused lately with how newer USB revisions work, and as I'm shopping for a new laptop, an important question came up in me.

So, a lot of laptops have some or all of their USB-C ports labeled with being capable of DisplayPort. This is clear.

But what about USB-C ports with no indication about this? Is it possible to connect a display to a "generic" USB-c 3.2 Gen 1 port? (frick this naming scheme, but I think that's 5 Gb/s) with a USB-C dongle that has HDMI?

Btw the exact laptop in question is the Vivobook Pro 14 OLED (M3401)[Ryzen 5000 series]
I couldn't find any info about it supporting anything like this.

This laptop ticks all the boxes for me, but if I can't connect two displays at once, that would be kind of a dealbreaker.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Is it possible to upgrade a basic USB-C to have USB-C Alternate Mode?](https://superuser.com/questions/1614732/is-it-possible-to-upgrade-a-basic-usb-c-to-have-usb-c-alternate-mode)

Comment: The long and short of it is that the USB C port needs to have some active switching capable of changing data pins to display output pins. Otherwise you would need a USB graphics chip or dongle which is essentially a graphics card with a USB port, which is NOT the same as an eGPU which repurposes the USB C pins for PCIe data. USB C support for this is a huge mess.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes.** There are four ways to get graphics using USB-C, depending on the port’s capabilities:

- DisplayPort over USB-C

  - 2 lanes
    The mode you get on most adapters and docking stations: 2 DisplayPort lanes + USB 3.2 Gen 1.
  - 4 lanes
    The mode you get on a select few adapters: 4 DisplayPort lanes + USB 2.0
- DisplayPort over Thunderbolt 3+ over USB-C
  Provides 4 DisplayPort lanes (or more on TB 4+), plus lots of other connectivity
- PCIe over TB 3+ over USB-C
  Connect an external “full” PCI Express graphics card (eGPU)
- DisplayLink over USB 2.0+ (so basically any USB-C)
  A (relatively) dumb USB graphics solution with no 3D acceleration and limited 2D performance, but enough for videos and office work

---

The laptop you link to has a full-size HDMI port.

Comment: Is HDMI over USB-C a thing?

Comment: @user1686 Not really. A specification exists, but I'm not aware of any actual devices.